# Coding with Sublime Text 2

Tags: sublimetext2

Simple question, I just started coding with Sublime Text 2 on windows, and I want to change little things, like when I am writing an if statement such as if (i > 0), immediately after I type the "0", my cursor is between the "0" and ")", so if I hit enter, I want it to jump to after the ")". I am used to eclipse so I want to know how I can get the settings to mimic those of eclipse. I have tried editing the settings text files but couldn't find what I was looking for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try adding the following to your User key bindings (accessible through `Preferences -> Key Bindings - User`)

```
{ "keys": ["enter"], "command": "move", "args": {"by": "characters", "forward": true},
  "context": [
    { "key": "selection_empty", "operator": "equal", "operand": true },
    { "key": "preceding_text", "operator": "not_regex_match", "operand": "[[:space:]]*", "match_all": true },
    { "key": "following_text", "operator": "regex_contains", "operand": "^[\\)]", "match_all": true },
    { "key": "auto_complete_visible", "operator": "equal", "operand": false }
]}
```

edit: Update regex to only match parentheses.

Comment: actually, I'm just an idiot, it worked perfectly, thanks alot

Comment: @abaratham No problem, I was confused because I did a quick test and it seemed to work. One side note though, I use something similar, but with tab as the keybinding, but for return you may want to remove the `\\}\\]` and `\"'` from the regular expression so it only works on parentheses. Edited answer to reflect the change.